# ¿Como usar correctamente los plugins de jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Resulta que estoy haciendo un menu de busqueda, pero la conexion con el jQuery no me funciona para ocultar el contenido del mismo. Cuando miro la consola de Google Chrome aparecen los siguientes errores:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
dataTable.min:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
buscador.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

¿Que podria tener mal?

Este es mi codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Practica</title>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min"></script>
<script src="js/dataTable.min"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="header-top">
        <div class="navegacion">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar..." id="inputBusqueda">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search" id="search">
    <table class="search-table" id="searchTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><em>Practica</em></td></a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><em>Msyql</em></td></a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><em>C++</em></td></a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href=""><em>HTML</em></td></a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<script src="buscador.js/js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi codigo JQuery:

```
var consulta= $ ("#searchTable").DateTable();
$("#inputBusqueda").keyup(function){
consulta.search($(this).val()).draw();
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Definitivamente el <script> de buscador.js esta mal deberia ser así: <script src="js/buscador.js"></script>, y ademas podrias mostrarnos donde tienes la carpeta de js y donde esta tu html, osea la estructura de tus documentos.

Comment: De acuerdo con @Ricardo el script al final debe ser así: `<script src="js/buscador.js"></script>` y la carpeta de tu proyecto debe contener una subcarpeta llamada **js** la cual debe contener los archivos  `jquery-3.3.1.min` ,  `dataTable.min` y `buscador.js`

Comment: Deje las imagenes sobre como tengo estructuradas las carpetas. Tambien corregi el error en el ultimo script, pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que tienes agregados los archivos dentro del tag  sin su extensión .js.

Como tu lo tienes:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min"></script>
```

Como deberia de ser:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

> .min significa que el archivo viene comprimido pero sigue siendo un
>   archivo javascript por lo tanto lleva su extension .js

En base al problema de tu Tabla de DataTable:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Practica</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
    <div class="header-top">
            <div class="navegacion">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Buscar..." id="inputBusqueda">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search" id="search">
        <table class="search-table" id="searchTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=""><em>Practica</em></td></a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=""><em>Msyql</em></td></a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=""><em>C++</em></td></a>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href=""><em>HTML</em></td></a>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrap">
    </div>
    <script src="js/buscador.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Prueba y me cuentas. Saludos.

Comment: Aparecen dos errores ahora, son: dataTable.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Mi%20pagina%20web/js/buscador.js/:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Cambia esta linea <script src="js/dataTable.min"></script> por esta <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: Listo, ahora el unico problema esta en la carpeta. Aparece el mismo error que te deje hace minutos.

Comment: Mira lo que me sale ahora: index.html:45 GET file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Mi%20pagina%20web/js/buscador.js/ net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Como tienes escrita la etiqueta <script> del buscador.js

Comment: <script src="js/buscador.js/"></script>

Comment: Si tu pegas esta ruta en tu navegador y no te trae nada, quiere decir que el archivo no existe en esa ruta y esta en otro lado: file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Mi%20pagina%20web/js/buscador.js/

Comment: Efectivamente no dio nada, pero se supone que tengo todo donde deberia estar supuestamente. No se si observaste las imagenes sobre como guarde los documentos; asi esta todo en este momento.

Comment: Ponlo de esta manera, deberia funcionar: <script src="js/buscador.js"></script>

Comment: Ahora mira los errores que salieron: jquery.dataTables.min.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined
    at Ha (jquery.dataTables.min.js:24)
    at O (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:17)
    at jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
    at Function.map (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.map (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at na (jquery.dataTables.min.js:16)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:92)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:93)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: En tu <tbody> dentro de tu HTML, tienes definido 1 <tr> abierto y 2 de cierre (</tr></tr>) y estos <tr> no tienen ningun <td> dentro de ellos, y el DataTable marca error por que necesita de eso para poder funcionar, modifiqué mi respuesta.

Comment: Funciono, Ricardo, muchas gracias.